# EF6/Code First: Super slow during the 1st query, but only in Debug

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 rc1 with Code First strategy, without precompiled views and the problem is:
If I compile and run the exe application it takes like 15 seconds to run the first query (that's okay, since I'm still working on the pre-generated views). But if I use Visual Studio 2013 Preview to Debug the exact same application it takes almost 2 minutes BEFORE running the first query:

```
Dim Context = New MyEntities()
Dim Query = From I in Context.Itens '' <--- The debug takes 2 minutes in here
Dim Item = Query.FirstOrDefault()
```

Is there a way to remove this extra time? Am I doing something wrong here?

Ps.: The context itself is not complicated, its just full with 200+ tables.

Edit: Found out that the problem is that during debug time the EF appears to be generating the Views ignoring the pre-generated ones. 
Using the source code from EF I discovered that the property:

```
IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return _provider ?? (_provider = new DbQueryProvider(
                                                 GetInternalQueryWithCheck("IQueryable.Provider").InternalContext,
                                                 GetInternalQueryWithCheck("IQueryable.Provider").ObjectQueryProvider));
        }
    }
```

is where the time is being consumed. But this is strange since it only takes time in debug. Am I missing something here?

Edit: Found more info related to the question:
Using the Process Monitor (by Sysinternals) I found out that there its the 'desenv.exe' process that is consuming tons of time. To be more specific its consuming time with an 'Thread Exit'. It repeats the Thread Exit stack 36 times. I don't know if this info is very useful, but I saved a '.cvs' with the stack, here is his body: [...] (edit: removed the '.cvs' body, I can post it again by the comments if someone really think its going to be useful, but it was confusing and too big.)

Edit: Installed VS2013 Ultimate and Entity Framework 6 RTM. Installed the Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 and used it to generate the Views. Nothing changed... If I run the exe it takes 20 seconds, if I 'Start' debugging it takes 120 seconds.

Edit: Created a small project to simulate the error: http://sdrv.ms/16pH9Vm
Just run the project inside the environment and directly through the .exe, click the button and compare the loading time.

Comment: This is a common problem that has plagued EF for quite some time, I thought they were going to address it in EF6.. but maybe not.. One thing EF6 provides is the ability to break up your model into multiple models, which may be your best bet.

Comment: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations

Comment: Breaking in multiple contexts changed nothing. All the contexts are following the 'rule', so it takes almost the same time to load them, unless I load on demand, but I need to load them all, since there is a lot of foreign keys between them.

Comment: Well, this is a common problem with large contexts, and the only way I know to fix it is to break your model out into smaller contexts that are not related.

Comment: But it works fine in VS2012, the problem is in VS2013 with EF6. The problem is not the time it takes to load itself, its the time it takes to load inside the VS201 IDE. When I run the application through the .exe it works just fine.

Comment: I just upgraded to EF6 + VS203 + MVC5 and I can now see the exact same issue. Considering that one of the advertised feature of EF 6 was increased start up speed for large models, this is disappointing (ps: I did install the very latest EF6 + patch through nugget, 6.0.1 as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx).

Comment: I can also confirm that upgrading from EF5 to EF6.0.1 increases 1st EF call time from 5s to 10s (double). We cannot speak about size of model, since time is benchmarked on the same model (My model contains  approx 20 mapped entities).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known performance issue in Lazy (which EF is using) when the debugger is attached. We are currently working on a fix (the current approach we are looking at is removing the use of Lazy). We hope to ship this fix in a patch release soon. You can track progress of this issue on our CodePlex site - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1778.

More details on the coming 6.0.2 patch release that will include a fix are here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/31/ef6-performance-issues.aspx

Comment: Thank you, since this is a know bug I'll mark as answer and keep track of the codeplex workitem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have found the solution. But in my case, I had similar issue which wasted me close to a week after trying different suggestions. Finally, I found a solution by changing my web.config to optimizeCompilations="true" and performance improved dramatically from 15-30 seconds to about 2 seconds.