# EF6 model creation very slow even with precompiled views

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have a rather large EF code-first model that takes a long time to spin up. With EF5 & pre-compiled views, the load time was 30-45 seconds. However, after upgrading to EF6.1, the load time is > 3 minutes. All of this work is happening before it even starts looking at the precompiled views.

By pausing the debugger, I determined that nearly all time is being spent calling SequenceEqual inside the anonymous function created by TablePrimitiveOperations.GetPropertyPathMatcher (see [the source](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Configuration/Mapping/EntityMappingTransformer.cs)). Using a profiler, I've confirmed that over 80% of the time is being spent in this method.

Are there any known fixes to this issue? I've posted it on [Connect](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2258) but I'm wondering if there's a workaround available currently.

Comment: What db init strategy do you use?

Comment: I would create custom db init strategy that doing nothing and create small console app that you will run only when db actually changed, that will use proper db init strategy.

Comment: @vittore: the database already exists (we migrate it manually), so we don't use an initializer (we set the initializer to null).

Comment: This seems related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539550/ef6-code-first-super-slow-during-the-1st-query-but-only-in-debug

Comment: @Shoe: I don't think that's related. That question refers to a different bottleneck which has already been fixed.

Comment: Try running a memory and disk profiler on your target machine, and also check for possible contentions and deadlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is an [actual bug in EF 6.1.0. MSFT has created a fix which is available in the 6.1.1 beta and will be available in the 6.1.1 release](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2258).